# Script to create multiple stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am testing a scenario with a high number of stored procedures in mssql.  Is there a way to script creating ~5000 stored procedures?  My attempts have been futile.

```
declare @id int 
select @id = 1
while @id >=1 and @id <= 1000
begin
    CREATE PROCEDURE 'SelectAllCustomer'+ convert(varchar(5))  AS SELECT * FROM Customers
    select @id = @id + 1
end
go
```

Fails with:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
> 'PROCEDURE'.

Even just adding a parameter to the procedure name is failing:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 'SelectAllCustomer'+ 'test' AS SELECT * FROM Customers
```

fails with:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near
> 'SelectAllCustomer'.

Comment: Why are you creating a pile of stored procedures that all do the same thing? That makes no sense. But if you really feel you need to do this you would have to use dynamic sql to generate them.

Comment: Strictly a test scenario.  Just need a large number of stored procedures.

Comment: What are you testing where you need 1000 procedures?

Comment: A customer hit a problem and they have 3500 procedures. Just need to recreate their environment.

Comment: Gotcha. Kind of odd but sometimes you have to do some odd things for support. ;) As I said previously you would have to use dynamic sql for this.

Comment: How about you tell us what problem they had

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Pretty straight forward.

```
declare @id int = 1
    , @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

while @id >=1 and @id <= 1000
begin
    select @sql = 'CREATE PROCEDURE SelectAllCustomer'+ convert(varchar(5), @id) + ' AS SELECT * FROM Customers;'
    exec sp_executesql @sql
    select @id = @id + 1
end
```